# @JoinFormula why hibernate prefixing boolean?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a OneToMany from Film to all their language Version(s) Entities
And i would like to also have a manyToOne toward the original Version.
This Version contains a boolean orginal = true to restrict the Versions to the only one having the attribute original = true.
So i tried a Forumla to restrict the Version :
     @JoinFormula(value = 
            "(SELECT v.id FROM persistence.model.Version v WHERE  v.film.id = id AND  v.original is true )
But when generating the SQL, hibernate prefixes true with film0_ so it does not work (in SQL you get fiml0_.true).
here is the code :

```
@Entity
public class Film implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "film")
    private Set<Version> versions = new HashSet<Version>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas( @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = 
        @JoinFormula(value = 
        "(SELECT v.id FROM persistence.model.Version v WHERE  v.film.id = id AND  v.original is true )", 
         referencedColumnName = "id")) })
    private Version originalVersion;

...
}

@Entity
public class Version implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String language;

    private boolean original;

    @ManyToOne
    private Film film;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that Hibernate prefixes the "true" literal with the Film alias (film0_) when generating the SQL, Why ?
How could i get rid of that ?

```
select film0_.id as id1_0_0_,  etc ...
_ from Film film0_ 
left outer join Version version1_ on 
(SELECT v.id FROM persistence.model.Version v 
  WHERE  v.film.id = film0_.id AND  v.original is film0_.true )=version1_.id
```

of course film0_.true  is not a column, how could i tell Hibernate that in that case true is a literal ?

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you map it as a ManyToOne? The original version is the original version of one and only one film, isn't it? Have you tried `= 'true'`? It seems to work fine with PostgreSQL, and I guess Hibernate won't prefix a literal string with the table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JBNizet thanks for your comment. 
I realized that i had made a stupid guess : that the formula was HQL, but it is **plain SQL** ! With That in mind, it's easier to make it work ; )
And you are right Postgres understant many syntaxes for boolean.

The Solution is :

```
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({ 
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = 
        @JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT v.id FROM version v WHERE id = v.film_id AND v.original = 'true' )", 
                    referencedColumnName = "id")) })
private Version originalVersion;
```

referencedColumnName = "id" means that the 'id' in the middle of the formula SQl comes from the id column from the FILM table so it will be prefixed by Hibernate with the correct alias (film0_ in my case) when generating the full SQL

Comment: can you please explain how `select v.id` fits together with the type of `originalVersion`, `Version`? how can an `id`   be cast into an object? shouldnt it be `select v`?